# How to add a node selector to a system pod in kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, scaling, horizontal-scaling

I want to apply a yaml file which will add a node selector to a pod matching `k8s-app=metrics-server` label. What should I put in the yaml file to this?

Comment: What do you mean `system pod`, pod which was automatically created with cluster? Are you using GKE from Google Cloud or its mistagged? You also used tags `scaling` and `horizontal-scaling`, you are not able to scale `pod`. You can scale `deployment` or `replicaset`, so if you would like to add node selector to pod and then be able to scale it, you would need to do it for example in `Deployment` yaml.
Please elaborate what you want to achievie or provide scenario.

Answer (score 0):

The Node should be labelled with the label *k8s-app: metrics-server* in order for pods to be scheduled on it.

Check if you have the labels added to the nodes of your cluster:
`kubectl get nodes --show-labels`

And the label should be **k8s-app: metrics-server**.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: testpod
spec:
  containers:
    - name: nginx
      image: nginx:latest
  nodeSelector:
    k8s-app: metrics-server
```

Also to check if the pod was scheduled on that node run the following command:
`kubectl get pods -o wide`

Then looking at the “NODE” that the Pod was assigned to.

Following is an excercise again from the kubernetes docs https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/#nodeselector

Also before you post up a question please try and check online if your question's answer is available. The more you dig, the deeper you will know. Kubernetes docs are too detailed and very easy to understand.